# Use Android phone as Android Wear device

Tags: stock-android, android-wear

I would like to install my old Android phone as a bike computer. As many apps now​ have support for Android Wear, it would be cool to be able to use that phone as a display for Google Maps Navigation and Runtastic tracking.

Is there any way to run Android Wear apps on an ordinary Android phone?